# Nethereum and UWP on .Net c#

Tags: dapps, .net, nethereum, c#

Is there a way to make Nethereum work with an UWP app ? Because when I try to download the package with nuget It raise an error. I enter the following command in Nuget Package Manager:

```
Install-Package Nethereum.RPC -Pre
```

And the console package manager raises an error say that packages can't be restored. Anyone have already experience this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Nethereum.Portable which has a wider compatibility. It includes Web3,RPC, ABI, Hex and supporting libraries.

In the future all the libraries will target netstandard 1.2 when is widely available.

There is an example now using Nethereum Portable, Xamarin.Forms and MVVM Cross for a portable example using UWP (Windows 10, Phone, Xbox, Raspberry PI), Android and iOS.

https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.UI.Wallet.Sample

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: The package seems to work well, however when I try to execute this line of code (herited from github example):
            var transactionHash = await web3.Eth.DeployContract.SendRequestAsync(abi, contractByteCode, addressFrom,"param");    It raises an exception: 
 'edjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClientUnknownException' dans mscorlib.ni.dll

Comment: Have you got the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes, http://pastebin.com/HP1QWehL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37962/discussion-between-juan-blanco-and-frank-lbt).

Comment: what's netstandard 1.2?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md